# Stream http response directly to S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to download a pdf file via http and upload it on a S3 Bucket.

The http response Content-Type is `application/pdf` and I'm trying to simply save/upload that file on S3.

```
http.get(options, function (resp) {
    resp.setEncoding('binary');
    var data = "";
    resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on("end", function () {
      var fileName = documentId + "___test.pdf";
      awsS3.uploadBinaryData(fileName, data, function (err, data) {
        return res.json(new CustomResponse('done'));
      })
});
```

and the `uploadBinaryData` method looks like this:

```
var params = {
    Bucket: config.get("S3.BUCKET_NAME"),
    Key: fileName,
    Body: data,
    ACL: "public-read",
    ContentLength: Buffer.byteLength(data),
    ContentEncoding: 'application/pdf'
}
  awsS3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) callback(err, err.stack);
  else {
    var path = buildS3Url(fileName);
    callback(null, path);
  }
});
```

The upload works, but the pdf content is messed up (I only see like 3 pages out of 12, some are empty, some contain weird characters).

It looks like an encoding issue, but I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Since `ContentLength` and `ContentEncoding` aren't required maybe try leaving that off? Let AWS figure it out.   Can you checksum validate that your initial download is succeeding?

Answer (score 0):

I have just figure it out this task with `aws-sdk v2.329.0`.

My Lambda:

```
const storage = require('./utils/save-to-s3');

module.exports.handler = (event) => {
  const { downloadUrl, fileName } = event;
  console.info(`Downloading URL ${downloadUrl} to storage`, event);
  return storage.saveUrl(downloadUrl, fileName);
};
```

My Utils:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');

AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });

const storage = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

function saveUrl(url, fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const protocol = url.startsWith('https') ? https : http;
    protocol.get(url, (response) => {

      const buffers = [];
      response.on('error', (err) => { reject(err); });
      response.on('data', (buffer) => {
        buffers.push(buffer);
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
        const uploadParams = {
          Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
          Key: fileName,
          Body: Buffer.concat(buffers),
        };
        resolve(storage.putObject(uploadParams).promise());
      });
    });
  });
}


module.exports = {
  saveUrl,
}
```

NB: remeber to config IAM policy with `s3:PutObject`